# Change archive page template using pre_get_post

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, pre-get-posts, archive-template

I've used [pre_get_post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os1Ej.png) to modify and display my custom post type in an archive page with pagination which uses my custom created archive template, see [here](https://prnt.sc/t4yurr). It it displaying the posts exactly what I need, however, it seems like it is not using my custom template. It is using the default template even though I already set a custom page template in my page settings. It is like [this](https://prnt.sc/t4yurr) when in default template, and should be like [this](https://prnt.sc/t4yv49) when using custom template.

Does everyone know how I can change the page template to my custom one when using pre_get_post?

I have tried the archive_videos_template() custom function that I found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087311/wordpress-pre-get-posts-in-place-of-query-posts-on-pages), which you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os1Ej.png) but it is not working.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to do this because I wanted to modify the template of my custom post type in a page.

Thanks

Here's my initial code in function.php to display custom post type in archive page with pagination and the other function that I tried to change page template.

```
function post_type_videos( $query )
    {
      if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'videos_cpt' ) && $query->is_main_query() )
      {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'videos' ); //set query arg ( key, value )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 ); //set query arg ( key, value )
        return $query;

        // custom page template
        add_filter( 'template_include', 'archive_videos_template', 99 );
      }
    }

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'post_type_videos', 1, 1 );

    function archive_videos_template( $template )
    {
        $target_tpl = 'archive-videos_cpt.php'; // EDIT to your needs

        remove_filter( 'template_include', 'archive_videos_template', 99 );

        $new_template = locate_template( array( $target_tpl ) );

        if ( ! empty( $new_template ) )
            $template = $new_template;;
    }

        return $template;
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Your code is in an image, please edit your question using the edit link to put your code in a code block, not a screenshot. In order to debug this I would have to type it all out manually, and I don't have the time to do that. Also can you clarify what you're trying to do that this solves? Why couldn't you use `archive-video_cpt.php`? There's a screenshot of the block editor in your question but I don't understand why it's there.

Comment: oh sorry. I edited my post and pasted the code. thank you for the reply

Comment: the screenshot of block editor shows the template that i used in that page which is the archive-video_cpt.php that I custom created, however, it is not being used when I try to display posts using pre_get_post. It is using the default template. I am not sure why

Comment: You have in code `add_filter( 'archive-videos', 'archive_video_template', 99 )` but there is no such filter. To filter the path of template use `template_include` filter hook, so change this line to `add_filter( 'template_include', 'archive_video_template', 99 )`.  You can also try with the [`archive_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/archive_template) filter.

Comment: oh, thanks, I'll try an get back to you

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't solved the problem, it's still using the default template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You corrected the filter hook name from `archive-videos` to [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/), but in the first function `return $query;`
statement comes before `add_filter()`, so the filter is not added.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'post_type_videos' );

function post_type_videos( $query )
{
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'videos_cpt' ) && $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'videos' ); //set query arg ( key, value )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 ); //set query arg ( key, value )

        // custom page template
        add_filter( 'template_include', 'archive_videos_template', 99 );

        return $query;
    }
}

function archive_videos_template( $template )
{
    remove_filter( 'template_include', 'archive_videos_template', 99 );

    $target_tpl = 'archive-videos_cpt.php';
    $new_template = locate_template( array( $target_tpl ) );
    if ( ! empty( $new_template ) )
        $template = $new_template;;
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Wooah. thank you for this adjustment. To be honest I am not an expert in wordpress so most of the time I am wondering what is this for what is that for. Thank you for this answer. works perfect, like what I wanted.